# Markers won't place unless I hard code numeric values Google Maps API iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I am parsing some JSON data and can print out the name, latitude, and longitude values just fine. When I try to place markers on my map however, I can't get the markers to show up unless I hardcode the values as numbers in the code, even though lat and long have the same value as the values I hard code. Any thoughts?

```
if let recyclePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "nyc_recycling", ofType: "json")
        {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: recyclePath)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return }

            for user in array
            {
                guard let dictionary = user as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else { return }
                guard let lat = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double else { return }
                guard let long = dictionary["longitude"] as? Double else { return }

                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)  //doesn't work
//                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.89084899, -73.86422392) //works
                marker.title = name
                marker.snippet = "test"
                marker.map = myMapView
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you checked what is coming in lat and long variables

Comment: Yes, like I said, lat and long have the same value as the hardcoded numbers I am using.